# Lookup on composite foreign key in Mongodb fluent C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, lookup, fluent-mongo

I need to make a lookup on a composite foreign key.

When I try it with a simple key like this, it is ok:

```cs
public async Task<List<AccountwithLinkedEntities>> Lookup(int institutionGroupId, long accountId)
{
     var filter = Builders<Account>.Filter.Eq(a => a.InstitutionGroupId, institutionGroupId)
                 & Builders<Account>.Filter.Eq(a => a.AccountId, accountId);
     var test = await _mongoDbContext.Accounts.Aggregate().Match(filter)
               .Lookup<Account, LinkedEntities, AccountwithLinkedEntities>(_mongoDbContext.LinkedEntities,
                   x => x.AccountId,
                   y => y.AccountId,
                   x => x.InnerLinkedEntities)
               .ToListAsync();
     return test;
}
```

But when I try my composite key on 2 fields for lookup like this:

```cs
public async Task<List<AccountwithLinkedEntities>> Lookup(int institutionGroupId, long accountId)
{
    var filter = Builders<Account>.Filter.Eq(a => a.InstitutionGroupId, institutionGroupId)
                & Builders<Account>.Filter.Eq(a => a.AccountId, accountId);
    var test = await _mongoDbContext.Accounts.Aggregate().Match(filter)
              .Lookup<Account, LinkedEntities, AccountwithLinkedEntities>(_mongoDbContext.LinkedEntities,
                  x => new { x.AccountId, x.InstitutionGroupId },
                  y => new { y.AccountId, y.InstitutionGroupId },
                  x => x.InnerLinkedEntities)
              .ToListAsync();
   return test;
}
```

I get this error:

> Expression not supported: new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(AccountId = x.AccountId, InstitutionGroupId = x.InstitutionGroupId).    "ExceptionType": "ExpressionNotSupportedException",   "StatusCode": 500,   "InnerException": null,   "StackTrace": "   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToFilterTranslators.ToFilterFieldTranslators.ExpressionToFilterFieldTranslator.Translate(TranslationContext context, Expression expression)\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.LinqProviderAdapterV3.TranslateExpressionToField[TDocument](LambdaExpression expression, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`3.<Lookup>b__0(IBsonSerializer`1 inputSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry sr, LinqProvider linqProvider)\r\n `

How can I solve this? Thanks